# Avalonia.UI ComboBox, no DisplayMemberPath or SelectedValuePath. TemplatedControl

Tags: combobox, avaloniaui

Avalonia.UI ComboBox doesn't have SelectedValuePath & DisplayMemberPath and I'm not skilled enough to implement them.
I have experimented with a TemplatedControl as a work-around because I'm using a TemplatedControl anyway and I don't want to have extra Properties on the ViewModel to handle it.
What I'm trying to archive is to show the items in the ComboBox by DisplayMember but loading/saving by Id. In this test case by Project.ManagerId. It's working but it would be nice not to have to hard-code the Type in that TemplatedControl code behind, like I do right now with "LookupItem". It should be possible to get around that by setting x:DataType="viewModels:LookupItem" or something.
Any ideas?

I have removed most not relevant code.

````
<Styles xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:controls="using:ChangeTrackingHeaderControls.Controls">
    <Design.PreviewWith>
        <controls:ChangeTrackingHeaderComboBox />
    </Design.PreviewWith>

    <Style Selector="controls|ChangeTrackingHeaderComboBox">
        <!-- Set Defaults -->
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <ControlTemplate>
                <ComboBox Items="{TemplateBinding Items, Mode=OneWay}"
                          SelectedItem="{TemplateBinding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          SelectedIndex="{TemplateBinding SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplate}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Styles>

public class ChangeTrackingHeaderComboBox : TemplatedControl
{
    private object? _selectedItem;
    private int? _selectedValue;

    public static readonly DirectProperty<ChangeTrackingHeaderComboBox, object?> SelectedItemProperty =
        AvaloniaProperty.RegisterDirect<ChangeTrackingHeaderComboBox, object?>(nameof(SelectedItem),
            o => o.SelectedItem,
            (o, v) => o.SelectedItem = v,
            defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
            enableDataValidation: true);

    public static readonly DirectProperty<ChangeTrackingHeaderComboBox, int?> SelectedValueProperty =
        AvaloniaProperty.RegisterDirect<ChangeTrackingHeaderComboBox, int?>(nameof(SelectedValue),
            o => o.SelectedValue,
            (o, v) => o.SelectedValue = v,
            defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
            enableDataValidation: true);

    public static readonly StyledProperty<IEnumerable> ItemsProperty = AvaloniaProperty
        .Register<ChangeTrackingHeaderComboBox, IEnumerable>(nameof(Items));

    public static readonly StyledProperty<int> SelectedIndexProperty = AvaloniaProperty
        .Register<ChangeTrackingHeaderComboBox, int>(nameof(SelectedIndex));

    public static readonly StyledProperty<IDataTemplate> ItemTemplateProperty = AvaloniaProperty
        .Register<ChangeTrackingHeaderComboBox, IDataTemplate>(nameof(ItemTemplate));

    public object? SelectedItem
    {
        get => _selectedItem;
        set
        {
            SetAndRaise(SelectedItemProperty, ref _selectedItem, value);
            OnSelectedItemChanged();
        }
    }

    public int? SelectedValue
    {
        get => _selectedValue;
        set
        {
            SetAndRaise(SelectedValueProperty, ref _selectedValue, value);
            OnSelectedValueChanged();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable Items
    {
        get => GetValue(ItemsProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemsProperty, value);
    }

    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get => GetValue(SelectedIndexProperty);
        set => SetValue(SelectedIndexProperty, value);
    }

    public IDataTemplate ItemTemplate
    {
        get => GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value);
    }

    protected override void UpdateDataValidation(AvaloniaProperty property, BindingValueType state, Exception? error)
    {
        base.UpdateDataValidation(property, state, error);

        if (property == SelectedItemProperty)
        {
            DataValidationErrors.SetError(this, error);
        }

        if (property == SelectedValueProperty)
        {
            DataValidationErrors.SetError(this, error);
        }
    }

    private void OnSelectedItemChanged()
    {
        // LookupItem should not be hard coded
        if (SelectedItem is LookupItem selectedItem)
        {
            if (SelectedValue == selectedItem.Id) return;

            if (Items is IEnumerable<LookupItem> items)
            {
                var selectedItemDisplayMember = selectedItem.DisplayMember;
                SelectedValue = items.SingleOrDefault(x => x.DisplayMember == selectedItemDisplayMember).Id;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnSelectedValueChanged()
    {
        // LookupItem should not be hard coded
        if (Items is IEnumerable<LookupItem> items)
        {
            if (SelectedItem == null)
            {
                SelectedItem = items.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == SelectedValue);
                return;
            }

            if (SelectedItem is LookupItem selectedItem)
            {
                if (selectedItem.Id == SelectedValue) return;

                SelectedItem = items.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == SelectedValue);
            }
        }
    }
}


// App.axaml
<Application xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ChangeTrackingHeaderControls.Controls"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:ChangeTrackingHeaderControls.ViewModels"
             x:Class="ChangeTrackingHeaderControls.App">

    <Application.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="LookupItemItemTemplate" x:DataType="viewModels:LookupItem">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="{CompiledBinding DisplayMember}"
                          HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                          VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Application.Resources>

    <Application.Styles>
        <FluentTheme Mode="Light" />
        <StyleInclude Source="/Controls/ChangeTrackingHeaderComboBox.axaml" />
    </Application.Styles>
</Application>`


// MainWindow
<controls:ChangeTrackingHeaderComboBox Items="{CompiledBinding Managers}"
                                       SelectedValue="{CompiledBinding Project.ManagerId}"
                                       ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LookupItemItemTemplate}" />



// ViewModel
public sealed class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Project _project;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Managers = new ObservableCollection<LookupItem>();

    // Simulating loading Managers from database
        for (var i = 1; i < 12; i++)
        {
            Managers.Add(new LookupItem
            {
                Id = i,
                DisplayMember = $"Manager {i}"
            });
        }
        
        // One single Project loaded from database
        Project = new Project
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Project 1",
            ManagerId = Managers.LastOrDefault()?.Id
        };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<LookupItem> Managers { get; }

    public Project Project
    {
        get => _project;
        private set
        {
            if (value == _project) return;
            _project = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}


// Models
public sealed class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ManagerId { get; set; }
}

public sealed class LookupItem
{
    public int Id { get; init; }
    public string DisplayMember { get; init; }
}```


I have tried to use x:DataType="viewModels:LookupItem" and also implemented StyledProperty<Type> but no succcess.
````

Answer (score 0):

On the `ViewModel` instances bound to the `ComboBox`'s `Items` property, override `ToString()` and return the value you want displayed in the open drop down.